# Flash Builder: AIR SDK 22 is not treating font style and font size same as AIR SDK 14?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I have a project build on AIR SDK 14 and when I try to upgrade my SDK to 22 and  build the same project with same Font Style and Font Size, the resultant build with SDK 22 is very different from project build in SDK 14.

The fonts size and style got differ (font size got smaller).
I have used font size 12 in my previous build but it looks good in that build but when I build the same project with the same 12 font size in the SDK 22 the font size appears to be 9 or 10 and also the font style is being treated differently from SDK 22.
So what I should do to get the same result with SDK 22?

Except that there are some labels are also missing from my HAccordion I tried every possible way but its not showing it, but its showing labels on VAccordion, but the tabs are viewing horizontal rather than vertical and I want tabs to be vertical.

PS: I also tried to increase font size and change font style but unable to get the same result, please suggest for both the issue.